# Concurrent Inserts/Updates on a Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two Processes: `P1` bulk-inserts fresh records into a table `Tab` every time it is executed. `P2` updates bunch of records on the same table `Tab`, based on a join with another buffer table `Buf` on a primary key.

The definition of `Tab` is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tab
(
Id [bigint] NOT NULL,
Val [float] NULL,
Status [tinyint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Status] ON [dbo].[Tab]([Status] ASC)
```

The definition of `Buf` table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Buf]
(
  [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [Val] [float] NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Id_Buf] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Id] ASC)
)
```

The update query is written as:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Status = 1
FROM dbo.Tab A WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN dbo.Buf B WITH(NOLOCK) ON A.Id = B.Id
WHERE A.Status IS NULL
```

Both `P1` and `P2` fire at their own time schedule, so at some point in time they will be both running at the same time. They do not touch the same rows, as this is maintained in the application layer. I noticed that `P2` always blocks `P1` (looking a `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`).

How do I rewrite the update statement in such a way that the other process can insert data without being blocked ?

Comment: *"Why doesn't the query hint (NOLOCK) prevent such locks? "* Because that isn't what `NOLOCK` does..

Comment: Also, putting `NOLOCK` in an `UPDATE` is a recipe for disaster. I suggest you read up on what `NOLOCK` *really* does, and you'll probably stop using it. It's *not* a *magic* "go faster" button, nor does it stop locks. There are, in my opinion, very few times you should be using that hint. [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the note, I will limit my question the to "How to re-write the query update statement to enable concurrent insert/update" on the table

Comment: Indexes details are important for concurrency. Add DDL to your question and [upload the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: @DanGuzman I added the DDL

Comment: Is the plan using the `IX_Status` index? How many roes are typically in the `tab` table and how many are typically updated?

Comment: You SAY that P1 and P2 do not affect the same rows, but how do you convince the query engine of that? Your update is looking at Tab.Status, which it doesn't know because of the insert.

Comment: @Larnu As I understand it, `NOLOCK` on inserts, updates and deletes doesn't even work fully anyway, as although S-locks are skipped, X-locks are always taken, which is obviously what is going on here

Comment: Are you using `TABLOCK` on the bulk insert? Have you tried a `ROWLOCK` hint on `dbo.Tab` in P2?

Comment: It shouldn't work fully, no, @Charlieface , but having in  the query is still a recipe for disaster. It could still work "properly" against the joined tables, creating duplicate joins when it reads a row twice, after it's moved or the data has changed, or get data from dirty reads; all of which will end up in the table you are updating.

Comment: @Larnu I actually don't mind dirty reads, my only concern is the performance of insert, which is blocked by the update process P1